# Reshaping Pandas data frame (a complex case!)

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I want to reshape the following data frame:

```
index   id     numbers
1111    5      58.99
2222    5      75.65
1000    4      66.54 
11      4      60.33
143     4      62.31
145     51     30.2
1       7      61.28
```

The reshaped data frame should be like the following:

```
id   1       2        3 
5    58.99   75.65    nan
4    66.54   60.33    62.31
51   30.2    nan      nan
7    61.28   nan      nan
```

I use the following code to do this.

```
import pandas as pd
dtFrame = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
ids = dtFrame['id'].unique()
temp = dtFrame.groupby(['id'])
temp2 = {}
for i in ids:
    temp2[i]= temp.get_group(i).reset_index()['numbers'] 
dtFrame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(temp2)
dtFrame = dtFrame.T
```

Although the above code solve my problem but is there a more simple way to achieve this. I tried Pivot table but it does not solve the problem perhaps it requires to have same number of element in each group. Or may be there is another way which I am not aware of, please share your thoughts about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [69]: df.groupby(df['id'])['numbers'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values)).unstack()
Out[69]: 
        0      1      2
id                     
4   66.54  60.33  62.31
5   58.99  75.65    NaN
7   61.28    NaN    NaN
51  30.20    NaN    NaN
```

This is really quite similar to what you are doing except that the loop is replaced by `apply`. The `pd.Series(x.values)` has an index which by default ranges over integers starting at `0`. The index values become the column names (above). It doesn't matter that the various groups may have different lengths. The `apply` method *aligns* the various indices for you (and fills missing values with `NaN`). What a convenience!

I learned this trick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17438511/190597).